# d3: color by separate array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map of us states, identified by fips codes and mapped with topoJSON.

I also have an array of fips codes and population `data = [{fips: 1, pop: 2000}, {fips:2, pop: 3240}, etc.]`

I am trying to color the states by population with the below code. Any thoughts on why it isn't working?

```
g.append("g")
  .attr("id", "states")
.selectAll("path")
  .data(state_features)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("d", path)
.attr("class", "state")
.style("fill", function(d) { 
     state = data.filter(function( obj ) { return obj.fips == d.id; })[0];
     return color(state.pop); })
.on("mouseover", tip.show)

svg.call(tip)
```

A similar idea works for my toolip:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
  .html(functioN(d, i) {
      state = data.filter(function( ob ) { return obj.fips == d.id;})[0]
      return state.pop;})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are very close. If you are using a regular GeoJSON and defined the data as `data(state_features)`, probably the `fips` keys are inside a collection called `properties`. If that is the case, you only need to add `properties` before `fips`, like this:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { 
   var state = data.filter(function( obj ) { return obj.properties.fips == d.id; })[0];
 return color(state.pop); })
```

That would explain why your `states` are `undefined`.

Also, it's a good idea to check, before filling the paths, if you have all the states in your `var data`, otherwise it will return undefined again. You can do this:

```
if (typeof state != 'undefined'){
  return color(state.pop);
} else {
  return someColorHere;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The way the topoJSON is set up, i actually want `obj.fips`. Your second check, however, was the problem. I used your code and now it is working - thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For `path`, you should use `attr` function, and `stroke` property:

```
g.append("g")
  .attr("id", "states")
.selectAll("path")
  .data(state_features)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("d", path)
.attr("class", "state")
.attr('stroke', function(d) { 
     var state = data.filter(function( obj ) { return obj.fips == d.id; })[0];
     return color(state.pop); })
.attr('stroke-width', 2)
.attr("fill", "none")
.on("mouseover", tip.show);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i get the error that `state is undefined`. also wouldn't stroke color the border?

Comment: that is strange, I added `var` in front of `state` and added `.attr("fill", "none")`, can you try?

Comment: it's only coloring in one state... it colors in all of them for you?

Comment: @As3adTintin it would be helpful if you can host your code to jsfiddle or jsbin where I can run it to see the issue.

Comment: @As3adTintin, indeed, you color the states using `fill`.

Comment: @paradite thanks for your suggestions. Gerardo suggested looking for missing states, which was the problem